# How to GET lists based on the basetemplate 106 on SP2013 using JS REST API?

Tags: sharepoint, rest, sharepoint-2013

I want to get only lists with basetemplate 106.

the code that i have now is :

```
 url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: onGetHostWebListsSuccess,
        error: onGetHostWebListsFail
```

This code will get all the lists from the site, thats a lot of information. But want to narrow it down. For lowering data traffic.

Any help in this regard would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $filter query option to select which items to return.

So in your case, the filter would look something like this:

```
$filter=BaseTemplate eq 106
```

And your URL like this:

```
appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 106&@target='" + hostweburl + "'"
```